# read CSV and load into gcp bucket using google cloud composer issue

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I started having strange issue when i try to read csv from gcp bucket and write to the same bucket.
Please note that the code below used to work for me before but now an exception is thrown in airflow logs saying

```
{models.py:1796} ERROR - Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 23 meaning 'Failed writing received data to disk/application', error details: Received 134221820 response bytes for a 134217728-byte buffe
     when reading gs://file_bucket/abc.csv
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1664, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 103, in execut
    return_value = self.execute_callable(
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 108, in execute_callabl
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/handle_split_rows.py", line 56, in handle_split_row
    lines= file_stream.read(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 132, in rea
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit_
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 23 meaning 'Failed writing received data to disk/application', error details: Received 134221820 response bytes for a 134217728-byte buffe
     when reading gs://file_bucket/abc.csv
```

code:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import os
> import json
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> from airflow import DAG
> from airflow.models import Variable
> from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
> from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
> from airflow.operators import python_operator
> from airflow.contrib.hooks import gcs_hook
> from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
> from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_table_delete_operator import BigQueryTableDeleteOperator
> from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator
> from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator
> from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_list_operator import GoogleCloudStorageListOperator
> from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor
> from airflow.operators import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
> from airflow.operators import BashOperator
> from lib import notification_utility
>
> default_args = {
>     'owner': os.environ["OWNER"],
>     'depends_on_past': False,
>     'start_date': '2019-10-10 09:31:00'
> }
>
> with DAG('parse_bad_rows',
>     default_args=default_args,
>     catchup=False,
>     schedule_interval= None
> ) as dag:
>     def parse_rows(**context):
>         import pandas as pd
>         import numpy as np
>         import csv
>         import os
>         import gcsfs
>         from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
>         from pandas.compat import StringIO
>         import io
>         #**tf.disable_v2_behavior() also tried disabling v1 just in case but i dont think it makes any sense**
>         #updated_file_list = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='list_files_delta_bucket_test')
>         fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project_name')
>         updated_file_list = fs.ls('/bucket_name/foldername/')
>         updated_file_list = [ x for x in updated_file_list if "abc" in x ]
>         print("updated_file_list------------------>",updated_file_list)
>         for f in updated_file_list:
>             print("File Being processed------->",f)
>             file_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
>            #**this is where the job is failing while reading the file so I am assuming it has to do something with tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io**
>             file_stream = file_io.FileIO("gs://"+f, mode='r')
>             lines= file_stream.read()
>             file_stream_less_cols   =io.StringIO(lines)
>             Split_Rows = [x for x in file_stream_less_cols if x.count('|') < 297]
>             Split_Rows = ' '.join(map(str, Split_Rows))
>             file_stream.close()
>             Split_Rows_Stream = pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(Split_Rows),columns=['BLOB_COLUMN'],dtype='str')
>             #Split_Rows_Stream['File_Name'] = Split_Rows_Stream.index
>             parse_names = file_name.split('/')
>             filename = parse_names[2]
>             bucketname  = parse_names[0]
>             Split_Rows_Stream['FILE_NAME'] = filename
>             print("bucketname------------>",bucketname)
>             print("filename------------->",filename)
>             Split_Rows_Stream.to_csv("gs://"+bucketname+"/ERROR_FILES/"+filename+".csv",encoding='utf-8',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar='|')
>
>     Python_Task_Split_Rows = PythonOperator(
>                              task_id= 'split_rows_to_process_test',
>                              provide_context=True,
>                              python_callable=parse_rows,
>                              #op_kwargs={'project':'project_name','bucket':'bucket_name','table_name':'abc','delim_num':297},
>                              #trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
>                              dag=dag
>                             )
>     # Orchestration
>     Python_Task_Split_Rows
> ```

I also tried the same in local so as to make sure csv is not an issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import io
import os
#Read the file
directory='c:\\Users\BG/Downloads/file_Cleansing'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file_name = filename.split('.')[0]
    f=open('c:\\Users\BG/Downloads/file_Cleansing/'+filename,'r',encoding="utf8")
    #Readlines forom the text file
    lines= f.read()
    #cleanse the lines
    file_stream   =io.StringIO(lines)
    Split_Rows    = [x for x in file_stream if x.count('|') < 297]
    Split_Rows = ' '.join(map(str, Split_Rows))
    f.close()
    Split_Rows_Stream = pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(Split_Rows),columns=['blob'])
    Split_Rows_Stream["File_Name"] = file_name
    Split_Rows_Stream.to_csv("c:\\Users\BG/Downloads/file_Cleansed/'+filename+"_error.csv",escapechar='|',encoding='utf-8')
```

the above worked as expected.
My goal is to find records that are not matching the number of delimiters expected for a row(basically my delim is pipe and there are 297 pipes expected per row as there are 298 columns in this csv but in some rows i have pipe in between data. )

and capture those records and load it into csv and then into a table in bigquery for  concatenating back the rows(using sql lead or lag as i am using the filename and index number for ordering and grouping) to repair and recover the records as many as possible.

Also lastly my service account has changed can this be some permission issue on GCP.

any advise appreciated.

Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue related to [permissions][1], verify your service account is listed within the bucket [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) and if it has the role to read and/or write

I had replicated you scenario with your code to read the file and it works correctly

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
import gcsfs
import os, io

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project_name')
updated_file_list = fs.ls('bucket')
updated_file_list = [ x for x in updated_file_list if "filename" in x ]
print("updated_file_list------------------>",updated_file_list)

for f in updated_file_list:
    print("File Being processed------->",f)
    file_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    #**this is where the job is failing while reading the file so I am assuming it has to do something with tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io**
    file_stream = file_io.FileIO("gs://"+f, mode='r')
    lines= file_stream.read()
    print(lines)
```

OUTPUT:

```
('updated_file_list------------------>', [u'bucket/file'])
('File Being processed------->', u'bucket/file')
this is a text from a file
```

Comment: Thank you for the time yes it most likely is permission issue I still havent figured out where the perminssions needs to be set. In the mean time I read the file using Pandas and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be a permission issue on GCP. Could you also check the GCS logs, maybe you can get there more information about this problem.